# How to set a Upstart job to start manually?

Tags: upstart

I want to disable a bunch of upstart jobs here. I know how to make a upstart job. And also I know how to stop manually a job. However, I can't find a sample where I turn a automatically job into a manually job. That is, I want the job to be started only when the user activate, for instance running this command (as root):

> `service job-name start`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for reference: Since upstart 0.6.7 (in Ubuntu since natty), there is a stanza called [manual](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#manual) designed for just this purpose.

Answer (score 15):

Delete or comment out the `start on` part (using the number sign '#'). Commenting it out has the advantage of easy recoverability of the original state.

Comment: You can also remove the *start on* part (or not add one, if you are writing a job yourself), but commenting it out is useful if you want to re-enable it later...

Comment: This one worked well. Autostart was disabled while I can manually start Mongod as a service. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @MvG, there is the `manual` stanza which declares an upstart service to be started manually only.

As root, put this into the `.override` file in `/etc/init/` matching your job name:

```sh
echo "manual" > /etc/init/${JOB-NAME}.override
```

or using sudo:

```sh
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/${JOB-NAME}.override
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache for example does not use 'upstart'.
Apache is old fashioned Sys V link starting in rc2.d

The clue is when a service is missing such as : '/etc/init/apache2.conf'

In such cases you need good old fashioned SysV techniques.

A starting point is :
Look for a README in /etc/init.d

Also GUI Tools exist for tweeking run levels

Nota Bene : upstart is getting depreciated, and eventually the distros are going to migrate to systemd. Oh what fun.